# Jenkins job not able to run ansible playbook on remote machine

Tags: jenkins, build, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

**Background:** I have my repo code with ansible playbook in Github. I created a jenkins job which clones this repo to the Jenkins docker agent and run the playbook in the build section of the job with the required creds. My build section of jenkins job looks something like below -

[image: Jenkins job to execute playbook on remote host]

**Problem:** Now when I execute the build, it runs infinitely, probably stuck at the ssh connection to the remote host part. Before it used to give "**Host key verification error**". I added the credentials for the new key to the Jenkins job and now the job is getting stuck while connecting to the remote host. I am able to ssh to the remote hosts with the same key but from Jenkins, I am unable to connect to the remote host.

The role of the Jenkins job is just to clone the repo to the docker container(Jenkins agent) and run the playbook on the remote machines specified in the nodes(inventory) file. Is there any way to fix this

Comment: `Host key verification error` means that there is something already in the _known_hosts_ of the Jenkins user for that server but that does not correspond to the server actual fingerprint. I would recommend you to SSH to your Jenkins box, as the `jenkins` user then see what is in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, and remove the offending line if you can identify it easily (some distribution hash those value, so it could be less trivial than what it seems). This said, this is not a programming question, but rather, so it is off-topic here.

Comment: there is no "host key verification error" now. I created the new key and added it to the Jenkins job, now the build is getting stuck at ssh to the remote host part. Also, the Jenkins build runs on the docker agent which shutdown once the build is complete. How could I possibly remove the known_host content for this docker container?